# How to initialize 3D array for deck of cards

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

```
// deck of cards
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i, j, k;
    char arr[4][13][14] =
    {
        {
            { heart one, heart two, heart three, heart four, heart five, heart six, heart seven, heart eight, heart nine, heart ten, heart jack, heart queen, heart king, heart ace }
        },
        {
            { diamond one, diamond two, diamond three, diamond four, diamond five, diamond six, diamond seven, diamond eight, diamond nine, diamond ten, diamond jack, diamond queen, diamond king, diamond ace }
        },
        {
            { club one, club two, club three, club four, club five, club six, club seven, club eight, club nine, club ten, club jack, club queen, club king, club ace }
        },
        { 
            { spade one,spade two, spade three, spade four, spade five, spade six, spade seven, spade,eight, spade nine, spade ten, spade jack, spade queen, spade king, spade ace }
        },
    };

    clrscr();
    printf(":::3D Array:::\n\n");
    for(i=0; i<4;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<13;j++)
        {
            for(k=0;k<14;k++)
            {
                printf("%d\t",arr[i][j][k]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Im getting an error where heart, diamond, spade, club have not been specified. however i set type char, can someone give me some pointers on how to fix this? I want a 3D array for my deck of cards, 4 rows (suits), 13 colums (two,three,...,ace) and 14 places for data (longest being diamond eight for example, taking 13 elements). Please help!

Comment: Your code suffers dearly, you have a multitude of errors.

Comment: Where are the definitions for `spade, heart, club, diamond, one, two, three...`?

Comment: use string instead of char and put those names inside a double quote.

Comment: I have to use char, im not allowed to use class string

Comment: You need to put those names in double-quotes for start; for example, `"heart one"`. When you are printing them, don't loop on the last index, and use `%s` instead of `%d`. Also, you are using C functions, so include `<cstdio>` instead of `<iostream>` and if you are not using `<string>` then don't include it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start building the declaration from the bottom up to help you
understand the declaration syntax better.

How would you declare an array of 14 `char`s?

```
char card[14] = "heart two";
```

Now, how would you create an array of 13 of those?

```
char suite[13][14] = {"heart two", "heart three", "heart four" ...};
```

Now, how would you create an array of 4 of those?

```
char deck[4][13][14] =
{
   {"heart two", "heart three", "heart four" ...},
   {"diamond two", "diamond three", "diamond four" ...},
   {"club two", "club three", "club four" ...},
   {"spade two", "spade three", "spade four" ...}
};
```

Comment: thank you R Sahu, definately made sense this way. Its been a few years since ive programmed and ive just recently gotten back into it. Your help was much appreciated!

Comment: @matt, you are welcome. Glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want something like this. Also, there is no 1 in a deck of cards.

```
const char *arr[4][13]=
{
    {"heart two", "heart three",...},
    {"diamond two", "diamond three",...},
    {"club two", "club three",...},
    {"spade two", "spade three",...}
};
```